# buttons are moving towards top when clicked

Tags: css

I have a live site in this [link](http://buypcgamecdkeys.com/). In that home page under featured product category you can see there are some products. Under every product there is a button called add to cart. Now ehen you click on add to cart button then you can see that the button will jump towards the top part, I am using chrome browser so check with it. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. Help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

**Update**

In that I have used position: absolute, this is used to make all the buttons in that row to aligned in a line. So if you are giving suggestions to remove that then keep in mind that I have to keep all these buttons in aligned.

Comment: are you talking about `featured games` section?

Comment: yes...the add to cart buttons..

Comment: please remove position:absolute and left:45px; in this class "div#content ul.products li.product a.add_to_cart_button" after that you have to adjust the buttons properly.

Answer (score 1):

Add :

```
a.button:active{
    top:inherit;
}
```

At the end of your css.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from

**div#content ul.products li.product a.add_to_cart_button**  on Line 2178  from  [style.css](http://buypcgamecdkeys.com/wp-content/themes/BuyGames/style.css)
 and set some other style.

Comment: I have used position absolute to align the buttons in a line. If I will remove this the the button will be no more aligned...so any other suggestons in which the buttons will be also inline?

Answer (score 0):

This rule in **assets/css/woocommerce.css** is causing the problem. It stretches the button on the active state which makes it take 100% of the height by setting the value of `top` to **1** while it already has it's `bottom` set to **0** pixels. So, remove this rule and you should be fine.

```
a.button:active, button.button:active, input.button:active, #respond input#submit:active, #content input.button:active {
    top: 1px;
}
```

---

**edit:**

Another dirty solution is to override the `top` property of the "Add to cart" buttons in the active state. Add this rule to your stylesheet and it will also fix your problem

```
.add_to_cart_button:active{
  top:auto!important;  /*Forces the top to it's default value*/
}
```